# Is there a way for Link model to query in the Navbar Links of my Django project

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

I created a Link model in my django project that loads in as navigation links in my base.html file which is the template that is being inherited by the other html files.

I have tried the usual way or at least the way i was taught using `Listview,`{% for %}

```
def view_link(ListView):
 context_object_name = 'links'
 Model = Links
```

```
Class Link(Models):
 link_name = models.CharField(max_length=265)
```

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
 <a class="navbar-brand">HOME</a>
 <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseMenu">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>
 <div class="navbar navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    {% for link in links %}
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">{{ link.link_name}}</a></li>
   {% endfor %}
 </ul>
 </div>
</nav>


I expect the to query the link_names i stored in my link model to query as links for my navigation bar but instead it returns blank but when i do it manually and add links one by one it shows all of the links
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please correct your model name in the view.

Model = Links

it should be  Model = Link.

Thanks.